# Error when Compiling on truffle: "InternalCompilerError: Solidity assertion failed"

Tags: solidity, truffle, error

had an odd one popup today and can't find much on it, hoping someone else has had it before!

When compiling my contracts I encounter an error: "InternalCompilerError: Solidity assertion failed"

I am running

- Truffle v5.4.18 (core: 5.4.18)
- Solc 0.8.11 (have played with different versions, all my contracts are ^0.8.4 or ^0.8.7
- OSX 12.2.1

I have had problems running on different node versions in the past so have tried on all of the below;

- v12.20.1
- v14.16.1
- v16.13.0
- v17.2.0

Exact output:

```
    Compiling your contracts
===========================
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/api/chainLinkOracalAPI.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/base/clubRegistary.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/base/hostedServiceControl.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/base/localClubRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/base/localVaultRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/base/rewardsRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IAdminToken.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IClubRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IFundsVaultData.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IModeratorToken.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IOwner.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IRewardsData.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IRewardsRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IVaultRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/IclubRegistry.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/interfaces/Im3mb3rs.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3m3rsLocalMotherContract.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3mb3rsLocalAdminToken.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3mb3rsLocalClubMotherContract.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3mb3rsLocalModeratorToken.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3mb3rsLocalVault.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/m3mb3rsRewardsRegistryMotherContract.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/security/administratorControl.sol
> Compiling ./onChain/contracts/security/hostedServiceControl.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/Chainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwnerWithProposal.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/ChainlinkRequestInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/ENSInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/OperatorInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/OracleInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/OwnableInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/PointerInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/BufferChainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/CBORChainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/ENSResolver.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/governance/utils/IVotes.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/governance/utils/Votes.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Checkpoints.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeCast.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol
> Compiling droplabmods/onChain/contracts/ERC721/ERC721A-Model.sol
> Compiling droplabmods/onChain/contracts/ERC721/ERC721AVoting.sol
> Compiling droplabmods/onChain/contracts/utilities/tokenIO.sol
> Compiling erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol
> Compiling erc721a/contracts/IERC721A.sol
> Compiling erc721a/contracts/extensions/ERC721AQueryable.sol
> Compiling erc721a/contracts/extensions/IERC721AQueryable.sol

InternalCompilerError: Solidity assertion failed

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.18 (core: 5.4.18)
Node v12.20.1
```

If running with node v14.16.1 i get:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at convertJsFunctionToWasm (/Users/elliottlinehan-cross/.config/truffle/compilers/node_modules/soljson-v0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.js:1:4130)
    at addFunction (/Users/elliottlinehan-cross/.config/truffle/compilers/node_modules/soljson-v0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.js:1:5488)
    at runWithCallbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:143:1)
    at compileStandard (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:207:1)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper [as compile] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:214:1)
    at Object.parseImports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/parser.js:41:1)
    at parseImports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/profiler/loadParser.js:24:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/getImports.js:19:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/getImports.js:8:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/getImports.js:4:1)
    at Object.getImports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/getImports.js:15:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/resolveAllSources.js:52:1
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-common/dist/src/profiler/resolveAllSources.js:5:42)
Truffle v5.1.41 (core: 5.1.41)
Node v14.16.1
```

Comment: Stripped back the contracts to compile and deploy less at a time.  It is a set of contracts that are causing the issues, just haven't found out witch yet

Comment: If the error persist and you have a github repo that can reproduce the error, then solc developers might help you identify where is the problem.